# "Are you happier?"

Tags: adjectives, conversation, comparatives

I was reading an English book. This is a snippet of a conversation below:

> But please tell us... do you like your job? Are you happier?

I am confused at *happier*. Why not use *happy*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The person who said this was comparing the present job with the previous job.

He is saying, "Are you happier with this job, than your other job?"

They could also use *happy*, that is also correct. But it would mean a different thing.

It would just mean "Are you happy with this job", but it wouldn't compare it with his previous job.
I suppose, they said *happier*, because they want to compare it with his previous job.

Comment: There's also Bill Withers *Hope She'll Be Happier*, for which his live performance at the Carnegie Hall 1973 must be one of the greatest performances ever given there by anyone (ducks to avoid avalanche of counterclaims! :)